# Decoding string in IBM task route exported template file (.ctms)

Tags: decode

Does anyone know how to decode the encoded string in IBM task route exported template file? I tried various ways of decoding such as Base64, none of them worked on the encoded string. a screenshot of part of the encoded string is as below. Thanks!

```
 <config>
    <Name><![CDATA[FSC Metadata File Collector]]></Name>
    <Description><![CDATA[This collector finds metadata files from specified directories according to filter criteria, submits the files described in the metadata file, and then submits the metadata file. .]]></Description>
    <ConnectorTypeKey>ibm.ctms.filesystem.Connector</ConnectorTypeKey>
    <TypeKey><![CDATA[ibm.ctms.filesystem.metadata_collect]]></TypeKey>
    <IsActive>1</IsActive>
    <TaskRouteId>46f15f20-5b89-4e89-9ea0-4051e62f44d8</TaskRouteId>
    <ScheduleConfiguration>UDC4aQAAAAAAAAAAbABhAEAwuGlfAGwA4wcIAHQAHAAOAAwADABrAOMHCAB0ABwADgAMAAwAawAAAAAAAAAAAA==</ScheduleConfiguration>
    <Configuration>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</Configuration>
    <ParameterMappings>
    </ParameterMappings>
  </config>
```

[sample encoded strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3RmI.png)

Comment: HI there, instead of posting a screen shot of the code. Please paste the text as code block. Links can disappear so its always best to post them. You can edit your post using the edit button underneath it.

Comment: Thanks Craig. just added the code block.